# How to create a list object from outerHTML value of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

please check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/3ugu9ynn/).

This has an outerHTML `var`. Now, I have to create it as a list of objects ; objects will be each row.
 
In this example the row number is 3 , but I will get it in a var like

```
var maxrow = $('#rownumber').val();
var TotalObject = [] ;
```

that will contain :

```
{
    {column1header :row1col1value ,column2header :row1col2value ,column3header :row1col3value,column4header :row1col4value },
    {column1header :row2col1value ,column2header :row2col2value ,column3header :row2col3value,column4header :row2col4value },
    {column1header :row2col1value ,column2header :row2col2value ,column3header :row2col3value,column4header :row2col4value }
}
```

Then, I have to send this list of objects to my controller action method with an ajax call :

```
[httppost]
public PartialViewResult MyAction(list<mymodel> model)
{


   return Partialview ("mypartialview",model);
}
```

`mymodel` also has `IEnumerable<mymodel>` where I have to transform `this` to `that`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach :

1. Clean the input with a regular expression
2. Split it into an array
3. Create an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators) for your data
4. Push the result into a JSON object
5. Send the JSON result with Ajax?

**EDIT:** I improved the *cleanup* regular expressions ; it should account for empty values now.
It is based on the HTML markup, which isn't valid in your example (missing `</tr>` or `<tr>` tags).

```js
var outerhtml = "\r\n\r\n<thead>\r\n\r\n<tr>\r\n\r\n<th>\r\n\r\ncolumn1header\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n</th>\r\n\r\n<th>\r\n\r\ncolumn2header\r\n\r\n</th>\r\n\r\n<th>\r\n\r\ncolumn3header\r\n\r\n</th>\r\n\r\n<th>\r\n\r\ncolumn4header\r\n\r\n</th>\r\n\r\n</tr>\r\n\r\n</thead>\r\n\r\n<tbody>\r\n\r\n<tr>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow1col1value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow1col2value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow1col3value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow1col1value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n</tr>\r\n\r\n<tr>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow2col1value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow2col2value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow2col3value</td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow2col4value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n</tr>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow3col1value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\n row3col2value\r\n\r\n </td>\r\n\r\n<td>\r\n\r\nrow3col3value\r\n\r\n</td>\r\n\r\n <td>\r\n\r\n row3col4value \r\n\r\n </td>\r\n\r\n</tbody>\r\n\r\n";

const data = outerhtml.split("\r\n").join("");
const [_,h,v] = /(?:<thead><tr>(.*)<\/tr><\/thead>)(?:<tbody>(.*)<\/tbody>)/igm.exec(data);

const headers = h.split("</th><th>")
                 .map(t => t.replace("<th>","")
                            .replace("</th>",""));

const values = v.match(/(?:<td>\s*(\s*\w*)\s*<\/td>)/igm)
                .map(t => t.replace("<td>","")
                           .replace("</td>","")
                           .trim());

const iterator = function(array){
  const coll = [...array];
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator](){
      let nextIndex = 0;
      return {
        next: function(){
          const _r = {
            [headers[0]] : coll[nextIndex],
            [headers[1]] : coll[nextIndex+1],
            [headers[2]] : coll[nextIndex+2],
            [headers[3]] : coll[nextIndex+3]
          };
          nextIndex += 4;
          return nextIndex <= coll.length ?
            {value: _r, done: false} :
            {done: true};
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
let json=[];
const tuples = iterator(values);
for(tuple of tuples){
  json.push(tuple);
}

console.log(json);
```

Comment: thanks . but may i know why it is creating only two object , there are three rows  .

Comment: It dismissed one of the empty values. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: there another problem suppose one of the cell in one of the row is not having any value  its taking next cells value

Comment: i have updated the fiddle with updated outerhtml https://jsfiddle.net/shaswatatripathy/r4bLa1af/

Comment: suppose I have a var which contains the row number , will it help in this logic

Comment: I think it's fixed now. Can you check with your test data?

Comment: ok, minor error in the values regex fixed (`\b` instead of `\s`). it works with [your new fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4bLa1af/9/). With the nature of the algorithm, you need to set the number of columns (which you could make dynamic, since `headers` is created dynamically). The number of rows is irrelevant ; the source data has to be consistent though (values by group of 4 `<td></td>` tags).

Comment: yes sir , its fixed , but the problem stated earlier if any of the cell in row does not contain a any value its getting error

Comment: It shoud be fixed. Look at the `column3header` value for `row 3` on [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4bLa1af/9/) : it's an empty string. I made a mistake earlier with the regex meta character : I used the boundary one instead of the whitespace one.

Comment: I checked with empty cells as well. Should work. Maybe you can make a fiddle if you find data that breaks the algorithm. Could you +1 if it was useful to you?

Comment: this is awsum sir . its all fixed